# Need to substitute a string in a file using puppet

Tags: puppet

I need help replacing a word in an apache Vhost's file using Puppet. My Vhost file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to substitute the `*` with the `$fqdn` facter variable on the first line. I don't want to use the apache module from Puppet Forge. I found `file_line` from the `stdlib` module but it is not able to substitute with a facter variable.

I could use the `exec` resource type which will run a `sed` command to replace * with the hostname, but I want to avoid doing that. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can in fact use `file_line` here:

```
include stdlib
$fqdn = $facts['fqdn']
file_line { 'virtual_host':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/path/to/httpd.conf',
  line   => "<VirtualHost ${fqdn}:80>",
  match  => '<VirtualHost \*:80>',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found my answer:

```
append_on_no_match => false,
```

Added that to the match statement; seems to prevent appending if no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this answer, is that if puppet doesn't match a string it still appends, and this cannot always happen, in fact, it often cannot happen.

I don't have an answer, but perhaps someone else might.   I would prefer a puppet answer vs me writing a script (with sed or perl).

Sincerely,

Some puppet user....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31530811)